# Powering ADSL modems using the -48V from the central node (DSLAM/ISAM)

Tags: power-supply

Is it possible to power ADSL modems/routers using the -48V from the central DSLAM/ISAM node just as the traditional analogue phones are powered through the two pairs of copper wires from the exchange. If this is so, what is the implications or the effect of this on the requirements of power at the central node?

Rephrasing the question to find out if there are ADSL modems/routers that are powered or can be powered using the -48V from the central DSLAM/ISAM node at the exchange just as the traditional analogue phones are powered with the pair of copper cables? This is to address the current power challenges that are experienced by most residential clients in most countries that do not have reliable power supply.

If there is no such solution in the market at the moment, this is a good business opportunity to manufacture ADSL modem/routers that is remotely powered from the exchange to address power cuts and yet the central node is powered by backup generators. This solution will make sure clients are always enjoying their services even though there is no power.

On the same not, a solution for FTTH services can also be persued.

Comment: Are you *sure* that in the countries you are talking about, the ADSL will have an 48V DC component? Because modern variants don't include the analog part, and hence no DC, at least AFAIK. And if the 48V DC component is included, because the analog part of the spectrum is still used for analog, then picking up the phone will change that voltage, and that might do interesting things if you try to use it as a power supply ... that said, I've never heard about a line-powered ADSL modem. Which doesn't mean it's not possible, of course.

Comment: I am not saying modems use -48V, I know ADSL modems are powered using 12V DC. My question is making use of the -48V and downgrade/upgrade this to suit what we want to do? I do appreciate your comment and really appreciate. Still waiting for more comments

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the power capacity.  A POTS instrument is expected to use less than a watt of power (e.g. only 15 to 20mA of current).  The typical ADSL modem is not optimized with low-power components, and consumes 5W or more.  *"This solution will make sure clients are always enjoying their services even though there is no power."* -- Not really, you still have to power the PC.  At some point 5G wireless will replace most phone lines.

Comment: I meant the ADSL line, not the ADSL modem, and yes, I understood what you want to do. But, for example, my ADSL line here doesn't have a 48V DC component (I measured). So even if I wanted, and if it was technically possible, I couldn't power it from the phone line. Hence the question "are you sure that in the countries you are talking about ADSL lines will have an 48V DC component, always."